# Thucydides is not starting any browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jbehave, thucydides

I am trying to execute standard demo project from archetype 'thucydides-jbehave-archetype'
It is running fine in Windows 7 machine but in Windows 8 machine, the browser is not opening at all.
Same projects  which works well with Firefox and chrome in a different machine, are getting failed on Windows 8 machine. 
Please note that Thucydides reports are generated successfully and also the demo project from 'easyb' archetype is working well (and launches browser)

Here is a snapshot from console:

```
TEST STARTED: Looking up the definition of 'blank'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Scenario: Looking up the definition of 'blank'
Given the user is on the Wikionary home page (PENDING)
When the user looks up the definition of the word '' (PENDING)
Then they should see the definition 'A common, round fruit produced by the tree Malus domestica, cultivated in temperate climates.' (PENDING)
@Given("the user is on the Wikionary home page")
@Pending
public void givenTheUserIsOnTheWikionaryHomePage() {
  // PENDING
}

@When("the user looks up the definition of the word ''")
@Pending
public void whenTheUserLooksUpTheDefinitionOfTheWord() {
  // PENDING
}
```

Note that above steps are fully implemented.

Here are my environment details:-
OS: Windows 8
IDE: Eclipse Juno
Maven Runtime: apache-maven-3.2.1
Java version: 1.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the resolution. This trivial thing gave me sleepless nights:

In Windows ensure that the absolute path of your project should not contain any spaces.

I removed spaces and its working :-)